# Backbone - not parse each model in collection after fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

How to prevent parse function for model in collection fetching?

```
    $(function() {
    var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url : function() {
                return this.urlRoot + this.id;
        },
        urlRoot: 'index.php?c=light&a=list_tasks_bb&ajax=true&task=',
        parse: function (response, options) {
            console.log(options);
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }
    });

    var TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Task,
        url: 'index.php?c=light&a=list_tasks_bb&ajax=true',

        initialize: function () {

        },
        parse: function (response, options) {
            return response.tasks;
        }
    });

    var Light = Backbone.Router.extend({
        el: $('#light'),
        routes: {
            "tasks/:id": "taskAction",
            "*page": "defaultAction",
        },

        initialize: function () {
            _this = this;
            this.tasks = new TaskList();
            this.users = new UserList();
        },

        taskAction: function(id) {
            this.task = new Task({id: id});
            $.when (
                this.task.fetch()
            ).then(function(zzz) {
                new TaskView({model: _this.task}).render();
            });
        },
        defaultAction: function(page) {
            $.when (
                this.tasks.fetch(),
                this.users.fetch()
            ).then (function() {
                new TaskListView({collection: _this.tasks}).render();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I have one model and one collection which I get through ajax fetch. I have no opportunity to change backend, so the json structure of tasks list is:

```
"contents": {},
"current": false,
"errorCode": 0,
"errorMessage": "",
"u": 4,
"tasks": [{
    "id": "12250",
    "t": "ZZZ",
    "cid": "24",
    "c": "2013-08-22 11:36:32",
    "dd": "02.09.2013",
    "sd": "02.09.2013",
    "pr": "300",
    "pid": "0",
    "atid": "1:4",
    "s": 0,
    "dl": ""
}, {
    "id": "12307",
    "t": "ZZZ",
    "cid": "42",
    "c": "2013-08-28 11:14:44",
    "dd": "05.09.2013",
    "sd": "28.08.2013",
    "pr": "200",
    "pid": "0",
    "atid": "1:4",
    "s": 0,
    "dl": ""
}, {
    "id": "12326",
    "t": "ZZZ",
    "cid": "2",
    "c": "2013-08-29 09:55:34",
    "dd": "31.08.2013",
    "sd": "29.08.2013",
    "pr": "200",
    "pid": "0",
    "atid": "1:4",
    "s": 0,
    "dl": ""
}],
"events": []
```

This is the reason why I'm using parse for collection. In this step everything is fine.
JSON structure for single task is:

```
"contents": {},
"current": false,
"errorCode": 0,
"errorMessage": "",
"u": 4,
"tasks": [{
    "id": "12250",
    "t": "ZZZZ",
    "cid": "24",
    "c": "2013-08-22 11:36:32",
    "dd": "02.09.2013",
    "sd": "02.09.2013",
    "pr": "300",
    "pid": "0",
    "atid": "1:4",
    "text": "XXXXX",
    "s": 0,
    "dl": ""
}],
"comments": [{
    "id": "48178",
    "text": "CCCC",
    "cid": "4",
    "con": "23.08.2013"
}],
"events": []
```

So i need parse again for fetch single task after "task.fetch()". After I added parse function in model it working fine until I started fetch collection, because after collection parse I already have correct model data, but model parse callback for each model again.

Do I have correct way to fix this or better will be try to change backend?

PS
Sure, I can do something like this:

```
  if(response.tasks) {
    return response.tasks[0];
  } else {
    return response;
  }
```

But I think it's not correct solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When [creating models for insertion in a collection](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-112), Backbone passes the future collection as an option to the model constructor which in turns forwards this option to `parse`. You could check this property and abort the parsing as needed:

```
var Task  = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse : function(response, options){
        if (options.collection) return response;
        return response.tasks[0];
    }
});
var TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Task,
    parse : function(response){
        return response.tasks;
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/dfMgR/

Comment: THANK YOU! you saved me A LOT of time.

Comment: It took me a day to spot the re-parse issue, savior for real.